# Simple explanation of android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" for beginner?

Tags: android, google-maps, manifest

What this number stands for 0x00020000 in uses-feature tag? In every tutorial people just type in the number for open gl but what it means and why exactly this number? I am trying to create simple navigation system for myself but I would like to know deeper informations about some parts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is explained in [the documentation:](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#glEsVersion)

> The OpenGL ES version required by the application. The higher 16 bits represent the major number and the lower 16 bits represent the minor number. For example, to specify OpenGL ES version 2.0, you would set the value as "0x00020000", or to specify OpenGL ES 3.2, you would set the value as "0x00030002".

Hexadecimal notation: `0x`, higher 16 bits: `0002`, lower 16 bits: `0000`.